# N-tuple based tic tac toe diverges in temporal difference learning

Tags: q-learning, temporal-difference-methods

I have n-tuple based tic tac toe. I already have perfect minimax player and perfectly trained table-based player. My n-tuple network consists of 8 different rows of 3 of the board as triplets having possible empty, X or O, and one bit defining who's move is now, so totally 2 * 3^3 = 54 states in tuple. I train and update weights with the idea of the pseudo code from "Learning to Play Othello with N-Tuple Systems" by Simon Lucas:

```
public void inGameUpdate(double[] prev, double[] next) {
  double op = tanh(net.forward(prev));
  double tg = tanh(net.forward(next));
  double delta = alpha * (tg - op) * (1 - op * op);
  net.updateWeights(prev, delta);
}

public void terminalUpdate(double[] prev, double tg) {
  double op = tanh(net.forward(prev));
  double delta = alpha * (tg - op) * (1 - op * op);
  net.updateWeights(prev, delta);
}
```

And the score is the sum of weights of those rows of 3. The temporal difference training generally works for n-tuple based tic tac toe and after several thousands games it mostly plays perfectly. But after a while it diverges from the perfection and oscillates between perfect and near perfect. I realized it was in situations like this:

```
OXO
X-O
-XX
```

I suspect because row that prevent opponent from winning has big value. And having two of such rows seems to be better than losing later.

I know I can have perfect player basing on this particular n-tuple network. I could just stop training after I reach perfection, but in bigger games I can't do that. I fiddled with different alpha in ranges 0.1-0.0001 and e-greedy epsilon 1%-50%, or adaptive. Increasing epsilon to about 50% somewhat mitigates this effect, but this value is mostly very big to use in other games.

Here are couple questions:

1. Does this effect have a name in the machine learning world? It values preventing opponent from winning. But if opponent has more opportunities to win, its value will be bigger, so that it will exceed the (negative of) losing value.
2. Aside from probably using different n-tuple networks and tweaking hyper-parameters, what can I do to mitigate or eliminate this effect?
3. In bigger games, this learning and n-tuple system give fairly good result, but I see big oscillations after certain points. I.e. in breakthrough game against 1-ply minimax, after it reaches about 60% winrate (testing 10000 games after training every 10000 games against itself), its winrate goes slitghly up, but in testing its winrate oscillates between 45-65%. Can this effect be caused by the problem I mentioned in 1.?